# Keychain: ask for certificate from command line

Tags: security, command-line, keychain

Is it possible to ask for certificate (.certificateRequest file) from command line?

I want to mimic behavior like Keychain -> Certificate Assistant -> Request for Certificate in Certificate Buro from command line.

Good tool `/usr/bin/security` does not provide requests to Certificate Buro. Maybe I wrong here.

Could anybody help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the supplied "certtool" program. The "r" option allows you to generate a new certificate signing request (CSR).

Comment: thanks! how to specify email and display name like [here](http://monosnap.com/image/m8AcWQxc77Uwazxo5mo5GX3k0jeqPv)

Comment: When you run the command, it will run you through a series of questions where you can enter for example the common name, email, country, etc. Please mark the question as answered, if this solves your problem.

Comment: so, I can't use it as a part of sciprt?

Comment: Sure, but you will have to feed those answers to the script via its stdin. You could use for example the program "expect" to do that in a neat way.